# MySQL 'AND' query not working as expected

Tags: mysql

I've got 3 tables i'm currently working on. Recipe, Ingredient and recipeIng.
It's the classic many to many situation, with recipeIng there to solve that problem.

However, i'm having trouble getting a what I assumed to be, a fairly simple 'AND' query. What i'm trying to achieve is searching for multiple ingredients at once. For instance:

```
SELECT r.recipeTitle AS recipe
FROM Recipe r
WHERE recipeID IN(
    SELECT r.recipeID
    FROM recipeIng il, Ingredient i
    WHERE (il.ingredientID = i.ingredientID)
    AND (il.recipeID = r.recipeID)
    AND (i.ING LIKE '%cheese%' AND i.ING LIKE '%salmon%')

);
```

While the query runs, it outputs nothing. I can't seem to see what i'm doing wrong here.
Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Your `i` refers in each case to the same row, so you'd only get a match if you had something like `i.ing = 'salmon cheese spread'`. One way to fix this is to have two ingredient tables, `i_one` and `i_two`.

Comment: you are selecting r.recipeID, I don't think alias r has 'scope' within that subquery, try changing the from clause in the second select query to  `FROM recipeIng il, Ingredient i, Recipe r`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `i.ING LIKE '%cheese%' OR i.ING LIKE '%salmon%'` instead of `AND`, and add `GROUP BY r.recipeID` with `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT i.ING ) = 2` to ensure that the selected `r.recipeID` have both `ING`:

```
SELECT r.recipeTitle AS recipe
FROM Recipe r
WHERE recipeID IN(
    SELECT r.recipeID
    FROM recipeIng il
    INNER JOIN Ingredient i ON il.ingredientID = i.ingredientID 
    WHERE il.recipeID = r.recipeID
      AND (i.ING LIKE '%cheese%' OR i.ING LIKE '%salmon%')
    GROUP BY r.recipeID
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT i.ING ) = 2
);
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/88c25/1)

So if the `r.recipeID` have only one of them only, then the `COUNT(DISTINCT i.ING )` won't be equal to 2 and there for it will be eliminated.

The `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT i.ING ) = 2` will give you those recipes that has exactly the two tags cheese and salmon only no more ingredients, if you are looking for those recipes that has at least both two ingredients, use `` `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT i.ING ) >= 2 ``.

This is *assuming* that ingredients are entered in the field `ING` as a one value per row.

Answer (score 3):

So basically you want the recipes that includes any of the ingredients you're querying on. This can be performed using simple straight joins:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(r.recipeTitle) AS recipe
FROM Ingredient i
INNER JOIN recipeIng il ON il.ingredientID = i.ingredientID
INNER JOIN Recipe r ON r.recipeID = il.recipeID
WHERE i.ING LIKE '%cheese%' OR i.ING LIKE '%salmon%'
```

The `DISTINCT()` makes sure that you're not seeing the same recipe twice in case it contains both ingredients.

<strike>If both ingredients must be present in the recipes, you must use `AND` instead of `OR`.</strike>

Comment: I think the two ingredients are separate, but in the same recipe? This would require the ingredient table to be aliased twice. Edit: aha, you've got an `OR` in there - carry on! +1

Comment: @halfer I'm on the fence between `AND` and `OR` here; it's up to OP to validate I guess.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your query can be massively simplified as you do not need the outer query. The following is exactly the same:

```
SELECT r.recipeTitle AS recipe
FROM recipeIng il, Ingredient i, Recipe r
WHERE (il.ingredientID = i.ingredientID)
AND (il.recipeID = r.recipeID)
AND (i.ING LIKE '%cheese%' AND i.ING LIKE '%salmon%')
```

Secondly, you don't need all those brackets.

```
SELECT r.recipeTitle AS recipe
FROM recipeIng il, Ingredient i, Recipe r
WHERE il.ingredientID = i.ingredientID
AND   il.recipeID = r.recipeID
AND   i.ING LIKE '%cheese%' 
AND i.ING LIKE '%salmon%'
```

Thirdly, you should INNER JOIN your tables to make the relationship between them clearer:

```
SELECT r.recipeTitle AS recipe
FROM recipeIng il JOIN 
     Ingredient i ON  il.ingredientID = i.ingredientID JOIN
     Recipe r ON il.recipeID = r.recipeID
WHERE i.ING LIKE '%cheese%' 
AND   i.ING LIKE '%salmon%'
```

At this point, the issue should be clear - there are 2 likely possibilities, and 2 is more likely than 1.

1) Your `ING` field stores all the ingredients for a recipe in a single field. If this is the case then you do not have a recipe who's ingredients call for both Cheese and Salmon.

2) Your `ING` field only stores 1 ingredient per row. However, you are asking for a single row which contains both `Cheese` and `Salmon`. This is not your intention, and the query is therefore wrong.

```
-- SELECT ALL RECIPES USING CHEESE *OR* SALMON
SELECT r.recipeTitle AS recipe
FROM recipeIng il JOIN 
     Ingredient i ON  il.ingredientID = i.ingredientID JOIN
     Recipe r ON il.recipeID = r.recipeID
WHERE i.ING LIKE '%cheese%' 
AND   i.ING LIKE '%salmon%'

-- SELECT ALL RECIPES USING CHEESE *AND* SALMON
SELECT r.recipeTitle AS recipe
FROM recipeIng il JOIN 
     Ingredient iCheese 
         ON  il.ingredientID = i.ingredientID 
         AND i.ING LIKE '%cheese%'  JOIN
     Ingredient iSalmon 
         ON  il.ingredientID = i.ingredientID 
         AND i.ING LIKE '%salmon%'  JOIN 
     Recipe r ON il.recipeID = r.recipeID
```

Please note the above are for example only - without knowing your schema, these are merely hints and suggestions :)